# How does Adobe Pass Auto-Authentication work?

Tags: authentication, identity, sso

At time marker [2:05 of this video,](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/project-primetime/adobe-pass-version-2/) he describes that Adobe Pass can automatically identify you based on your broadband provider, and sign you in/authorize you for media content.

Can anyone describe the technical process in which this occurs, and what specific information is shown to whom... namely

- Adobe
- The content provider (CNN)
- The cable company (Comcast/RCN)
- The app provider (most apps are developed by a 3rd party)